# IF-Condition coloring cell

Tags: excel

I'd like to compare 2 cells (A1 and A2 - both formatted hh:mm) and color one cell, A3, depending on the result of the comparison of A1 and A2.

> A1: Hours per day to work: 8
>
> A2: Hours worked: 8

Pseudo Statement

```
IF (
  A1 = A2,
  "",
  IF ( 
    A1 > A2,
    COLOR_CELL( A3 ),
    IF (
      A1 < A2, 
      COLOR_CELL( A3 )
    )
  )
)
```

I researched but I only found that you can use conditional formatting. This doesn't seem to help me ... is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to color a cell using conditional formatting.  What is your objection to that method?

Comment: well your code looks like the second if is impossible....

Comment: do you wish to do it with Excel or VBA?

Comment: I'd like to compare 2 cells (A1 and A2 - both formatted hh:mm) and color one cell. So I'd say my object is a cell e.g. A3. I'd like to do it in Excel, but I won't deny an solution using VBA.

Comment: Again, why cannot you use conditional formatting?  It would seem to be the simplest solution.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld because I can't multiple events on one cell using conditional formatting

Comment: Sure you can.  I will post a response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote that you could not use conditional formatting *because I can't multiple events on one cell using conditional formatting.* Note in the screenshot that we have multiple rules applying to cell A3, which is colored according to those rules:

[image]

Comment: When I read the post from Ste Bov I already tried to get more into it and I found out how to do what you did. Anyway thanks for your help sir. One last question: I'm planning to build my own sheet for calculating work-hours ... if I want to use those rules, I guess I can applie them to more then one cell using default excel syntax, right?

Comment: Yes you can.  Just check the Rules Manager window to ensure it comes out the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Formatting is exactly the thing you're looking for to do this, outside of that you can use VBA to change the colour of the cells, but that's really long and clunky and needs to be set away unlike conditional formatting which works on the fly

There's no 'only in cell' function that can change the colour of the cell

I know you said no conditional formatting but it really is the thing you want to use, and it works across excel, google sheets and other things

- Highlight area you want to use
- Home -> Conditional Formatting -> Create new rule
- Use a formula to determine which cells to format

`=$H9<$I9` note that this is an example, you want the $H to be the row that the allocated time is, the $I to be the actual time, and then both 9s are replaced by the top row that you want to effect

also note that you appear to have the columns downwards so adjust accordingly to where they need to go (without seeing the sheet and how it fits together I cant give you the exact formula to use

- set the format to what ever you want
- click ok
- select add rule
- repeat process but change the < to > this time and set the formatting accordingly and click ok
- Set the Applies to to the range of cells you want to have the highlight on it
- click the ok
- hey presto, done

Ste